# Potential Energy of a Molecule

Tags: electrostatics, potential-energy

A generic problem asks that we find the total potential energy of a water molecule. Potential energy is given by $\Sigma \ kQ_{1}Q_{2}/r$ where $Q_{1}$ and $Q_{2}$ are the charges of any one bond pair's atoms.

In these problems, potential energy is either positive or negative, yet one energy signage (whether positive or negative) allows the system to stay together. A system with the opposite of **that** signage will break apart.

Which signage is that and why would the arrangement stick together?

- What I understand:

Take two charged particles. If the potential energy between them is (-), both particles "submitted" to being moved by their electrostatic forces. So, both particles, if left to themselves, would travel closer together. If the potential energy is (+), particles come to these positions by working *against* their electrostatic forces. So, both particles would, if left to themselves, travel apart.

I don't see why, consequently, any signage would permit the arrangement to exist as it does.

[image]

Comment: What do you reckon the answer is?

Comment: The sign really depends on your choice. It is customary to view potential energy from the inside of a system, rather than from the outside, so energy that is binding is lost to the system and is counted negative. That's just a convention, there is no deep scientific reason to make that choice. The good blue skinned folks in the Grand Sirius Academy of Applied Sciences may be teaching it the other way around.

Comment: @CuriousOne How would you view potential energy from the inside as opposed to from the outside of a system?

Comment: Think about it the same way you think about money. You buy candy for a dollar. For your account that transaction is negative (an expense) for the store account it's positive (income) but it's the same dollar. So while a stable compound forms, it gives off some energy, while the environment gains some. One way you account for the energy with a minus sign, the other way with a plus sign.

Comment: Ah ok. This is what I understand: For the given problem, a net positive potential energy (from the standpoint of the system) is more stable than a negative one. A net positive is more stable, because for the arrangement's members to have a positive potential, they **must lose kinetic energy** More importantly, though, it's important to realize that this finding holds when we examine the system and not the environment. We could easily swap our definition to focus on the environment, in which case an environment that lost $\Delta U$ is favorable.